# Need regex to match first instance until next instance (excluding next "look-ahead") Java

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I'm new to programming and regular expressions so that's my disclaimer.

I'm trying to parse my way through a wireshark log that I've transferred over to a txt file using tshark.

The point of my program is to start at the top of the txt file and match all text between packet headers.

All packets begin with `Frame\s+\d`, which excluding the next packet header and drop that text in a string.

I'm instantiating an object (`Packets`) and then adding them to an `ArrayList` for later processing.

I need to gather all text from packet header 1 to end of packet 1 / beginning of packet header 2, without including packet header 2.

```
Frame 1 (186 bytes on wire, 186 bytes captured)
    Arrival Time: Sep 19, 2013 13:25:19.937150000
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.000000000 seconds]
    Frame Number: 1
    Frame Length: 186 bytes
    Capture Length: 186 bytes
    [Frame is marked: False]
    [Protocols in frame
............................A bunch of more packet data...............
    Encrypted Packet: 88FE0AFA38B3E1994B907F778FC42CD4FBD967F3D9101679...

Frame 2 (60 bytes on wire, 60 bytes captured)
    Arrival Time: Sep 19, 2013 13:25:19.938495000
    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001345000 seconds]
    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.001345000 seconds]
```

I've tried:

```
(Frame\s\d)*.?Frame\s\d
```

But not dice.

I've been plugging away on rubular.com to see if I can hit paydirt on this but I can't seem to match what I need.

Thoughts?

Comment: You probably mean `.*?`, not `*.?`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering a file `packets.txt` in `/your/path`, containing the example you posted...

Here's a solution.

```
try {
    // trivial file operations
    String path = "/your/path/packets.txt";
    File file = new File(path);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
    String line = null;
    StringBuilder contents = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        contents.append(line);
    }
    br.close();
    // the Pattern
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Frame\\s\\d\\s(.+?(?=Frame|$))", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    // If you actually need the "Frame etc." header matched as well, here's
    // an alternate Pattern:
    // Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(Frame\\s\\d\\s.+?(?=Frame|$))", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    // matching...
    Matcher m = p.matcher(contents);
    // iterating over matches and printing out group 1
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(1));
    }
}
// "handling" FileNotFoundException
catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output:

```
Found: (186 bytes on wire, 186 bytes captured)    Arrival Time: Sep 19, 2013 13:25:19.937150000    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.000000000 seconds]    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.000000000 seconds]    [Time since reference or first frame: 0.000000000 seconds]    
Found: (60 bytes on wire, 60 bytes captured)    Arrival Time: Sep 19, 2013 13:25:19.938495000    [Time delta from previous captured frame: 0.001345000 seconds]    [Time delta from previous displayed frame: 0.001345000 seconds]
```

Explanation of the `Pattern`:

- It looks for text starting with your original pattern more or less ("Frame, space, digit, space")
- It stores whatever comes next including line breaks, but stops when either a new "Frame" text appears, or the end of the input text does
- The text matching point 2 is stored in a group (group 0 is the whole match, specific groups start at index 1)

**Edit: hints on performance and memory optimization**

- Small step but obvious: declare the `Pattern` as a constant so it compiles only once
- Instead of populating an `ArrayList` which will grow with every match, write each match to a single file in some folder - this will perform slowly, but if well implemented, should allow garbage collection to take place for the matched `String` at each iteration of the `while (m.find())` loop
- Once the iteration has terminated, you will have to process each small file iteratively again
- If this is not sufficient or just doesn't work against the size of your data, you might want to implement your own custom parser, or pre-chunk the data somehow, but this is quite out of scope, considering your original question was about the `Pattern` itself, not the performance

Comment: There are 2 slight problems here... the first being that I need everything in each packet to store in individual array elements. So just the header won't work, so I apologize if that wasn't clear from my original post. The second problem comes in the form of a heap space error. This solution works fine for small files, but on a 280MB log file the thing simply runs out of memory and stops. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: I had already given this a spin using an FR and a BR to read each line and append them all using something like "line += line + "%";" to add a small delimiter after each appended line and it was working fine for small files. The minute the files grew in size, my solution was no longer suitable due to the lack of memory. I figured the thing to do here is read all lines until the next instance of Frame\\s\\d and process that string into the array, then reset the string to empty again and parse once more until next iteration of header. It's clear in my head, just not in my code.

Comment: @jvazquez getting an `OutOfMemoryError` for the heap means that you've created way to many objects that aren't getting garbage collected. That might happened because you are adding each match to an `ArrayList`, and the latter keeps growing while the references still point out to `Object`s in memory. I'll edit my answer shortly with a few bullet point that might be helpful to you.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Being a novice really tests your perseverance, because I've been wanting to punch the wall a few times already. LOL

Comment: @jvazquez well you've got quite a decent challenge ahead for a novice, so punching the wall is understandable :D

Comment: Good news ... we have a working program now. So here's how I changed the program. I created a Boolean to keep track of new packets and used the aforementioned regEx to find those. When I find a new packet I set Boolean to true and then I added while loops to handle new packets or "not" new packets. A new packet flag means first process current packet which includes adding it to arrayList, then StringBuilder's .setLength(0) to clear it, and then append new packet header. I ran this on that 280MB file and it ran for about 15 seconds, which I deem acceptable at this time.

Comment: I used some of your tips above and I picked the brain of an experienced developer friend of mine. Thank you for the help and ideas here. Needless to state, but I'm very excited to have even a small success like this early on. Thanks again. Cheers!